# How to submit the right errorcode to trap

Tags: bash, error-handling, bash-trap

If some error (>0 and not 194) occurs in my script I want to make an API call and report it. But the function that should be triggered by trap, doesnt get executed when tested with exit 1.

I'd expect the function createIncidentOnErr to get executed. But the script exits immediately.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
function createIncidentOnErr (){
echo "some api call"
}

trap 'if [ $? -ne 194 ]; then createIncidentOnErr;' ERR
function checkOS (){
exit 1
}
checkOS
```

I also tried this alternative and expect it to be executed if exit is not 0. But it also gets executed on exit 0.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

function createIncidentOnErr (){
echo 'exit because of errorcode '"$?"'. do some api call'
}

trap 'if [[ $? -ne 0 || $? -ne 194 ]]; then createIncidentOnErr; fi;' EXIT

function checkOS (){
exit 0
}
checkOS
```

This is the outcome of the aforementioned code:

```
bash -x ./test.sh
+ set -e
+ trap 'if [[ $? -ne 0 || $? -ne 194 ]]; then createIncidentOnErr; fi;' EXIT
+ checkOS
+ exit 0
+ [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]
+ [[ 0 -ne 194 ]]
+ createIncidentOnErr
+ echo 'exit because of errorcode 0. do some api call'
exit because of errorcode 0. do some api call
```

Comment: The last test is certainly a logic error; you want `if [[ $? -ne 0 && $? -ne 194 ]]` with AND, not OR.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was a logic error.